# Saving JQuery UI Draggable position with a cookie, working but with a slight off set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cookies

On my website I have a basic JQuery UI draggable, I am saving its position using the js-Cookies plugin found at:

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

I have the code working but my problem is there is a slight offset to where the draggable element was before refreshing the page and reading the cookie. At the moment the JS/JQuery is in the  wrapped around a  element with the HTML, I know this is bad practice and will be changing it soon, code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   //JS Using the JQuery Cookie plugin framework to set the top/left in cookie
   function draggableCookie(top, left)
      {
          Cookies.set('draggableTop', top + "px");
          Cookies.set('draggableLeft', left+ "px");
      }

   //Set the div to be draggable, but disabled as true, buttno press will turn to true
   $( "#draggable" ).draggable();

   // Set the position of the element from the cookie
   $("#draggable").css({
            top: Cookies.get('draggableTop') , 
            left: Cookies.get('draggableLeft')
            });

});
```

So far it works it does remember a position but its a slight offset to the original, and is draggable it even prints out the coords when I stop moving with an alert, it is just on the reload the position of the elements are not correct, although it does save them into a new position.

Thanks

Comment: Have you made sure it's not an issue with borders or margins?

Comment: @Joonas89 Yes I have tried different settings, as well as removing the style sheets with just a blank HTML/CSS document

Comment: Also, if it has ends up having values with decimals, it wont be 100% the same when you try to render it again with the same values, as something cant be half a pixel

Comment: So you should use the grid property, and only allow it to be moved in increments of 1px or something, so u dont get those wierd values

Comment: How/when is `draggableCookie` invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem by adding a style property to the draggable div tags like below:

```
<div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content" style="position:absolute" >
  <p>Random buttons</p>
</div>
```